# Typus: Using another attribute that is not foreign key in edit form to set object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, typus

I've been using [Typus](https://github.com/typus/typus) for my rails application. I have the following models:

```
model List
  has_many :ListItems

  # attributes
  id   : integer
  another_id: integer

model ListItem
  belongs_to :List
```

When editing a ListItem, I want to be able to specify the `another_id` to designate the list, but it seems like you can only use `id`. `another_id` is unique to each record. Is there a way to change that? I've taken a look at the documentation and it's not very thorough.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreign_key`

```
belongs_to :list, foreign_key: 'another_id'
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to